# How to TDD and Design Recursive function?

Tags: design-patterns, recursion, tdd

I'm wondering if there is any best practice in applying TDD to the design of recursive function. My concrete case is a function that navigate a Graph.

I am always coding this function like a butcher, usually in one method.

Hence now a fervant of TDD, and refactoring to pattern, i am wondering if there is a good way to TDD a recursive function, if one apply the appropriate pattern such as strategy pattern, composed method, etc....

I think one thing could be to separate the logic of traversal from the actually operation done on the node, but i don't see how....

Any suggestion?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

IMMO doing a recursive method for solving a problem its an implementation choice, in general you don't want to test implementation details.

If at some point in the future you decide to change to a iterative function the test don't need to be changed and serve to verify that the new implementation offers the same results than the previous one.

Comment: Sounds like a good approach but the case is just to easy. Although what i see is that if you grow from the terminal case to the top case it sounds feasable http://ivarconr.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/tdd-by-example-factorial/ It is more in the code of conduct than in the pattern. However Of course you can use composed method with that

Comment: Growing from the simple scenario and conduct the implementation with scenarios in growing complexity its the typical TDD approach off course. But with the same tests you can implement an iterative factorial if you want, this is the key. The test stay in the "problem space" the production code in the "solution space", iterative vs recursive is a decision for the solution space.

Comment: I agree with your comment. However one key advantage that i see coming naturally, is that you can test private method more easily through the public method (i.e. where private method are understood as your different case). I don't know why i did not see it before. That is, recursive function align themselves with the TDD process naturally: in other words the answer to my question was really not complicate.